firebase realtime fetch categories with swift
I'm taking the data from the database, the data comes down correctly.
services
  -Ghkgkkjgkjg
    category: "veterinarian"
    name: "Ghkhkjhkjh"
  -Jljlkjlkj
    category: "veterinarian"
    name: "HJHGJH"
  -KJkjhkjhkj
    category: "trainer"
    name: "hkjhkjhkjhh"

Now I would like to create another tableView with only the categories, in this example I would like 2 rows to appear in the tableView:
veterinarian 
trainer
Then the user taps for example on "veterinarian" and will load another tableView with only the veterinarians, this is my code and I can't see just the category rows.
struct ServiceModelRead {
    var idService: String?
    var category: String?
    var name: String?
}

var serviceArray = [ServiceModelRead]()

self.serviceArray.removeAll()
        
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
let ref = rootRef.child(RefDatabase.services.rawValue)

ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    
    if let todoDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
        
        for (_,todoElement) in todoDict {
            print(todoElement);
            var serviceModel = ServiceModelRead()
            serviceModel.category = todoElement[RefDatabase.category.rawValue]?.stringValue
            
            self.serviceArray.append(serviceModel)
        }
        
    }
    
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}


Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. It's much more likely that someone can help if you debug locally, and tell us the results of that. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?
